# Identifying the date less than a given date and applying criteria to the data

Tags: r

I have four data tables, three of which has dates of three different procedures and one table has a date of infection and signs for diagnosing the infection. Firstly, I want to identify which procedure was associated with signs of infection and then apply the predetermined criteria to identify if it was the actual infection or not. Time for onset of infection is difference between infection date and procedure date (last procedure done just before infection). To identify which procedure is associated with infection we consider time difference between date of the procedure last done before the onset of infection and date of infection as less than one year. The criteria for infection is time to onset of infection less than one year after the procedure, fever = yes , discharge = yes, and culture = positive.

I did use merge function to merge various tables first and then used as.duration to identify the difference between dates of procedure and infection but that looked bizarre.
Could anyone please help me with this?  Example of my data is as follows.

```
dt1 = data.table(
  participant.id = c("1","2","3", "3"),
  date.procedure1 = c("2000-11-19", "2003-08-29", "2000-01-08", "2002-03-08"),
repeat.instance.procedure1 = c("1", "1", "1", "2")
)
dt2 = data.table (participant.id = c("1","2","3"),
                  date.procedure2 = c("2000-10-19", "2003-07-02", "1999-12-12"),
                  repeat.instance.procedure2 = c("1", "1", "1")
)
dt3 = data.table (participant.id = c("1","1", "2","2" ,"3"),
                  date.procedure3 = c("2002-10-19","2004-10-10", "2006-10-02", "2010-10-10",       "2009-01-12"),
                  repeat.instance.procedure3 = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1")
)
dt4 = data.table (
  participant.id = c("1", "2", "3"),
  date.infection = c("2001-05-10", "2007-02-10", "2002-03-25"),
  repeat.instance.infection = c("1", "1", "1"),
  fever = c("yes", "no", "yes"),
  discharge = c("yes", "no", "yes"),
  culture = c("positive", "positive","negative"),
  pain = c("yes", "yes", "yes")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow what you are looking for, I think you want to stack the first three tables into one table and create a field "type" for the procedure (1, 2 or 3).  Then as each patient is only infected once, you can merge in infection date with a left join.  Then you can construct a variable of the difference between the infection date and the treatment date for each row and determine if it is positive and less than 365.  I did this with both the packages sql_df and dplyr to check the result.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)

dt1 <- data.table(
  participant.id = c("1", "2", "3", "3"),
  date.procedure1 = c("2000-11-19", "2003-08-29", "2000-01-08", "2002-03-08"),
  repeat.instance.procedure1 = c("1", "1", "1", "2")
)
dt2 <- data.table(
  participant.id = c("1", "2", "3"),
  date.procedure2 = c("2000-10-19", "2003-07-02", "1999-12-12"),
  repeat.instance.procedure2 = c("1", "1", "1")
)
dt3 <- data.table(
  participant.id = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3"),
  date.procedure3 = c("2002-10-19", "2004-10-10", "2006-10-02", "2010-10-10", "2009-01-12"),
  repeat.instance.procedure3 = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1")
)
dt4 <- data.table(
  participant.id = c("1", "2", "3"),
  date.infection = c("2001-05-10", "2007-02-10", "2002-03-25"),
  repeat.instance.infection = c("1", "1", "1"),
  fever = c("yes", "no", "yes"),
  discharge = c("yes", "no", "yes"),
  culture = c("positive", "positive", "negative"),
  pain = c("yes", "yes", "yes")
)
tables123 <- list(dt1, dt2, dt3)
for (i in 1:length(tables123)) {
  toadd <- data.frame(tables123[[i]])
  toadd$date <- as.Date(toadd[, 2])
  toadd$type <- i
  toadd <- toadd[, c(1, 3:5)]
  names(toadd) <- c("id", "instance", "date", "type")
  if (i == 1) {
    dsn <- toadd
  } else {
    dsn <- rbind(dsn, toadd)
  }
}

dsn
```

which returns:

```
> dsn
   id instance       date type
1   1        1 2000-11-19    1
2   2        1 2003-08-29    1
3   3        1 2000-01-08    1
4   3        2 2002-03-08    1
5   1        1 2000-10-19    2
6   2        1 2003-07-02    2
7   3        1 1999-12-12    2
8   1        1 2002-10-19    3
9   1        2 2004-10-10    3
10  2        1 2006-10-02    3
11  2        2 2010-10-10    3
12  3        1 2009-01-12    3
```

Then merge in the infection date and create the variables difference and associate

```
toJoin <- dt4[, 1:2]
toJoin$infect_dt <- as.Date(toJoin$date.infection)
toJoin[, date.infection := NULL]
names(toJoin) <- c("id", "infect_dt")


dsn2 <- left_join(dsn, toJoin, by = NULL)
setorder(dsn2, id, date)
dsn2 <- mutate(dsn2, diff = as.numeric(infect_dt - date))
dsn2 <- mutate(dsn2, associate = (diff > 0 & diff < 635))
dsn2

# or

dsn2_sql <- sqldf("select a.*, b.infect_dt from dsn as a left join toJoin as b 
      where a.id=b.id order by id, date ")

dsn2_sql$diff <- as.numeric(dsn2_sql$infect_dt - dsn2_sql$date)
dsn2_sql$associate <- (dsn2_sql$diff < 365 & dsn2_sql$diff > 0)
dsn2_sql

dsn2_sql
```

which returns:

```
> dsn2_sql
   id instance       date type  infect_dt  diff associate
1   1        1 2000-10-19    2 2001-05-10   203      TRUE
2   1        1 2000-11-19    1 2001-05-10   172      TRUE
3   1        1 2002-10-19    3 2001-05-10  -527     FALSE
4   1        2 2004-10-10    3 2001-05-10 -1249     FALSE
5   2        1 2003-07-02    2 2007-02-10  1319     FALSE
6   2        1 2003-08-29    1 2007-02-10  1261     FALSE
7   2        1 2006-10-02    3 2007-02-10   131      TRUE
8   2        2 2010-10-10    3 2007-02-10 -1338     FALSE
9   3        1 1999-12-12    2 2002-03-25   834     FALSE
10  3        1 2000-01-08    1 2002-03-25   807     FALSE
11  3        2 2002-03-08    1 2002-03-25    17      TRUE
12  3        1 2009-01-12    3 2002-03-25 -2485     FALSE
```

and then filter out the FALSE associates

```
dsn2_sql <- sqldf("select a.*, b.infect_dt from dsn as a left join toJoin as b 
      where a.id=b.id order by id, date ")

dsn2_sql$diff <- as.numeric(dsn2_sql$infect_dt - dsn2_sql$date)
dsn2_sql$associate <- (dsn2_sql$diff < 365 & dsn2_sql$diff > 0)
dsn2_sql

dsn2_sql

dsn3 <- filter(dsn2, associate == T)
dsn3
dsn3_sql <- dsn2_sql[dsn2$associate == T, ]
dsn3_sql
```

which yields

```
   id instance       date type  infect_dt diff associate
1   1        1 2000-10-19    2 2001-05-10  203      TRUE
2   1        1 2000-11-19    1 2001-05-10  172      TRUE
7   2        1 2006-10-02    3 2007-02-10  131      TRUE
11  3        2 2002-03-08    1 2002-03-25   17      TRUE
```

you can check the work with

```
dsn3 == dsn3_sql
```

Patient one received two treatments a month apart and was then infected about 6 months latter.  You can select the last row for each patient via:

```
dsn3$keep = c(dsn3$id[1:(nrow(dsn3)-1)] != dsn3$id[2:(nrow(dsn3))],1)
```

and then filter where keep == 1.  Hope that this answered your question.